# Linear Algebra Question about Root Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

There is a statement in Humphreys' *Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory* that says essentially the following:

> Let $E$ be a Euclidean space, and let $\Phi$ be a finite set that spans $E$. Suppose that $\sigma\in GL(E)$ leaves $\Phi$ invariant, and fixes pointwise a hyperplane $P$ of $E$, and moreover sends some $\alpha\in\Phi$ to its negative. Show that $\sigma=\sigma_\alpha$, where $\sigma_\alpha$ is reflection across the hyperplane $P_\alpha=\{\beta\in E:(\beta,\alpha)=0\}$.

The idea of the proof is to show that the minimal polynomial of $\tau=\sigma\sigma_\alpha=1$ is $T-1$. I am a little confused by what is going on at the beginning of the proof. We have that

> Observe that $\tau(\Phi)=\Phi)$ and $\tau(\alpha)=\alpha$, and $\tau$ acts as the identity on the subspace $\mathbb{R}\alpha$ as well as on the quotient $E/\mathbb{R}\alpha$. So all eigenvalues of $\tau$ are $1$.

I guess what I don't understand is how the statement about the quotient is true. It seems like if we pick some $v+\mathbb{R}\alpha$ and apply the induced map from $\tau$ we get something like $w+\mathbb{R}\alpha$. But I'm not sure then how $v-w\in\mathbb{R}\alpha$.

Comment: I just remembered https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4131835/96384 and compared to there, it seems your paraphrasing of the lemma misses the seemingly small hypothesis that **all $\sigma_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$ leave $\Phi$ invariant**. Seems innocent but would exclude Hagen von Eitzen's counterexample to that statement.

Comment: Update: This lemma and its proof has confused yet another person, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4227594/96384, and they scanned the exact statement and proof. As suspected above, your paraphrasing misses a crucial hypothesis, whose lack allows for the counterexample in Hagen von Eitzen's answer. But with the hypothesis, lemma and proof work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

s stated, the claim is wrong.

Let $E=\Bbb R^2$, $\Phi=\{(42,0), (3,3), (-3,-3)\}$ and $\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. Then

- $\Phi$ spans $E$
- $\sigma$ swaps the second and third element of $\Phi$ while leaving the first fix
- $\sigma$ fixes pointwise the $x$-axis hyperplane

But $\sigma$ is not the reflection across $P_{(3,3)}$ (the antidiagonal).

---

I suppose you want $\sigma\in O(E)$.

Comment: Ironically, the very claim that OP doubts is true though, in your example and in general. Would be interesting to see where exactly the proof goes wrong later.

Comment: Seems like OP missed the additional hypothesis in the textbook that all $\sigma_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \in \Phi$ leave $\Phi$ invariant, which is obviously not the case in this counterexample. I would think now with that hypothesis, the claim is true -- or can you cook up a counterexample even under that assumption?

Answer (score 6):

While Hagen von Eitzen shows the first claim in your post is not true in general, the second one which you doubt is true.

In fact, once you've convinced yourself that $\sigma$ and $\sigma_\alpha$ induce well-defined actions on $E/\mathbb R \alpha$ at all, just notice that $E= P +\mathbb R \alpha = P_\alpha + \mathbb R \alpha$. Hence every element of the quotient has a representative in $P$, so $\sigma$ acts trivially on the quotient, and every element of the quotient has a representative in $P_\alpha$, so $\sigma_\alpha$ acts trivially on the quotient.